# C++: Keeping rvalue reference implicitly for fields of a smart pointer

Tags: c++, c++11, smart-pointers, move-semantics, unique-ptr

Let `f()` be a function that returns a `unique_ptr<X>` and let `m` be a member field of `X`. While `f()` can be used as an rvalue reference, `f()->m` cannot, forcing me to use `move(f()->m)`.

Assuming that I can define my own `unique_ptr` instead of using the existing one, is there a way to make my `->` operator keep the rvalue-ness? If this is not recommended, please explain why.

EDIT: To all people telling me to add a getter. I am trying to avoid adding special support in X, I want to do it through the unique_ptr only. Also, your solution can be improved by using a right reference for this as in the following example:

```
struct X {
    SomeType m;
    const SomeType &getM() const { return m; }
    SomeType &&getM() && { return move(m); }
    SomeType &getM() { return m; } 
}
```

Comment: AFAIK you can't you have to call move explicitly like you do, or have the move in a member function in `X` (rather than directly access `m`), `operator->` has to return a **pointer** (in this case to `X`) and you cannot hijack the member accessed...

Comment: Add a reference-qualified getter for `x` that returns `std::move(x)` when `*this` designates an rvalue. There's no way to do it for arbitrary members  AFAIK.

Comment: ...then this is not possible, once the `operator->` returns the pointer, the `unique_ptr` plays no part in the subsequent expression.. you *need to modify* `X` in some way..

Comment: If C++ had something like Template Haskell (including `reify`), then one could make it so that unique_ptr's operator * would return a completely newly created class where each member field is replaced by some kind of a proxy that gives you move reference to the original. I think we are too far from that for now.

Answer (score 2):

As long as you are accessing the value `m` by name, this can never be an r-value without casting. You could however add a member function which "moves" the member value out of your object.

```
using IntPtr = std::unique_ptr<int>;
class X {
    IntPtr m;
public:
    X();
    IntPtr getM() { return std::move(m); }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Hide the move... (undeleted as I think this could be one way of solving it without having to have your own custom `unique_ptr`) and I guess it's in keeping with encapsulation...

```
#include <memory>
#include <iostream>

struct foo
{
  std::string m;
  std::string m_()
  { return std::move(m); }
};

std::unique_ptr<foo> get_foo()
{ return std::unique_ptr<foo>(new foo{ "Bar" }); }

void bar(std::string&& r)
{ std::cout << r << std::endl; }

int main()
{
  // bar(get_foo()->m);  // this does not compile
  bar(get_foo()->m_());  // this is happy...
}
```

Now you should be good to go...